# Problema ao exportar dados de datagridview c# para planilha do excel

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-excel

Bom dia pessoal, tenho o seguinte código abaixo, nele estou estou pegando os dados do datagridview e exportando para um .xls, estou passando tudo como String, os textos, nomes, que são Strings, ficam normal, porém existem números com até **44 dígitos** que passo como String, e o excel já faz o favor de converter para notação cientifica, mais quero o numero completo.

Exemplo, Pego de um .xml e jogo no datagrid, assim: **35222200000238000800050010000000000007977111**

E na planilha esta me exportando assim:
**3,52222E+43**

```
SaveFileDialog salvar = new SaveFileDialog();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application App;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook WorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet WorkSheet;


        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        WorkBook = App.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        WorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)WorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView2.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView2.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
            {

                DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView2[j, i];
                WorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value.ToString();

            }

        }

        salvar.Title = "Exportar para Excel";
        salvar.Filter = "Arquivo do Excel *.xls | *.xls";
        salvar.ShowDialog();

        WorkBook.SaveAs(salvar.FileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCurrentPlatformText,misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue,
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared,misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        WorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        App.Quit();
```

Comment: Pelo tamanho deste número, creio que o excel somente o exibirá se for como texto. No "for" das colunas você consegue identificar esta coluna que contém este valor?

Comment: sim, a primeira e a sétima coluna, ambas tem valores que estão sendo convertidos em notação cientifica.

Comment: Faça um if para identificar a coluna, caso for a coluna desejada, antes da instrução "WorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value.ToString();" verifique se isso vai funcionar (não testei) WorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1].NumberFormat = "@" e depois atribua o valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz o exemplo:

```
for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
{
    DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[j, i];
    if (j == 2)
    {
        WorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1].NumberFormat = "@";
    } 
    WorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value.ToString();
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara fiz exatamente a mesma coisa, porém não funcionou, o NumberFormat não auto completa em Cells. não dá para chamar nenhum método aqui, estão usando qual versão ? adiciocou que versão de referencias ? do excel interop ?

Comment: Mas aconteceu algum erro ou simplesmente não foi apresentado o valor conforme queria?

Comment: sem erros, apresentando o mesmo valor notação cientifica.

Comment: No meu caso o NumberFormat também não se auto completou, mas eu o coloquei assim mesmo, a versão do interop que usei é a Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library (1.8.0.0)

Comment: Puts muito estranho, será que pode o modo em que crio o datagrid interfere, porque crio o data por meio de um datamember, estou fazendo do seguinte modo, recebo varios xml de consultas, dai pego todos e junto em um arquivo só, trato tags etc. depois exibo pelo datamember atribuindo o node root que criei para o conjunto de arquivos.

Comment: creio que não, pois o valor a ser atribuído na célula vem da célula do datagridview como string. Eu bindei o grid com uma lista<T> e está funcionando normalmente. Você depurou pra ver se está entrando na linha que contém a instrução de format?

Comment: Sim depurei, até testei esses exemplos de formatação deste site http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-format-excel.htm

Comment: Aqui foi feito da mesma forma que fiz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067926/format-an-excel-column-or-cell-as-text-in-c

Comment: Consegui revolver se uma forma muito simples rsrsrsrs, com sua ajuda e uma variável String que jogo os valores e essa variável na célula ! valor = cell.Value.ToString();
                    WorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1].NumberFormat = "@";
                    WorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = valor.ToString();